# Do type inference apply in Java non generics

Tags: java

This is how [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) define type inference:

> Type inference is a Java compiler's ability to look at each method
> invocation and corresponding declaration to determine the type
> argument (or arguments) that make the invocation applicable. The
> inference algorithm determines the types of the arguments and, if
> available, the type that the result is being assigned, or returned.
> Finally, the inference algorithm tries to find the most specific type
> that works with all of the arguments.

Below, it explains type inference using all examples of generics.

My questions is : Do type inference in Java only applies when generics come into play ? If not, an example or two will be helpful where we can see it ?

Comment: Interesting question. But I think that the algorithm is used each time due of the polymorphic nature of Java's classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In lambdas you do not have to specify argument types, and return types as well, they are automatically deduced. For example:

```
listOfStrings.stream().
        map((aString) -> {
              //do something
             anObject anobject = new anObject();
            return anobject;})

        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The type of the returned list is `List<anObject>`, and I did not have to specify that aString is of type String as it is infered by the listOfStrings type.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was: "not necessarily"; as the compiler since ever would have into analyzing method arguments to select a matching method when overloading takes places (like in understanding which foo(int) versus foo(long) versus foo(double) should be called for for some `foo(x)`).

But well, this is about *terminiology*. So the fact that "some computations" are required to detect the correct overloaded method doesn't mean that the "java fathers" think that these computations account for "type inference".

To the contrary: the Java language specification has a whole chapter about [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html); and when you study that closely, it is "only" about generic types and lambdas.

So the answers seems to be: when *Java* people use that term, it is solely about generics/lambdas; and not about other situations where the argument types need to be analyzed.

Comment: Please give reference that method overloading needs type reference so that I can accept it.

Comment: I just did, but coming more to the conclusions that the other answers give.

Comment: Sorry. I did not get you. I mean You explained how a type inference can be related to overloading. I am not able to verify that plus the down vote adds more confusion.

Comment: I tried to rephrase. My point is: my initial answer was wrong; or maybe; not precise enough.

Answer (score 1):

It would not make much sense to have type inference in a true non-generic environment, because otherwise you and the compiler would already know the type and don't need the compiler to interfere anything.
However the closes example I could find is about `Target Types`. From the docs

Take a method which is declared as this

```
void processStringList(List<String> stringList) {
    // process stringList
}
```

And you call it with this

```
processStringList(Collections.emptyList());
```

Since `Collections.emptyList()` is returning a `List<Object` if no target is specified it will throw an error

```
List<Object> cannot be converted to List<String>
```

Here the compiler is not able to interfere the type arguments for `List<>`. You have to explicitly provide the target type like

```
processStringList(Collections.<String>emptyList());
```

However with JDK 8 that's not necessary anymore. [Oracle docs Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)

> This is no longer necessary in Java SE 8. The notion of what is a target type has been expanded to include method arguments, such as the argument to the method processStringList. In this case, processStringList requires an argument of type List. The method Collections.emptyList returns a value of List, so using the target type of List, the compiler infers that the type argument T has a value of String. Thus, in Java SE 8, the following statement compiles:

So in the last example the compiler interferes the type argument to get a `List<String>` from `Collections.emptyList()`.

Comment: Type inference uses Target Types. Target Types is not a valid example for Type Inference.  `Inference algorithm uses only invocation arguments, target types, and possibly an obvious expected return type to infer types.` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html